# What is causing Postgres error 'Operation not permitted'?

Tags: postgresql, docker, macos, docker-compose, permissions

I have been trying to create a Postgres database using the following docker compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_DB=root      
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./migration/docker-database-initial.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/docker-database-initial.sql   

  pgadmin-compose:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "kaio@mail.com"
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "******"
    ports:
      - "54321:80"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

It tries to initialize a table with this script:

```sql
create table wikis(
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar,
    bio varchar
);

INSERT INTO wikis(name, bio) VALUES
('Name1', 'Bio1.'),
('Name2', 'Bio2.');
```

After the db is created and connected to the postgres container host, the table is not initialized. I've found this error log during the build process:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/docker-database-initial.sql
psql: error: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/docker-database-initial.sql: Operation not permitted
```

Expected output:
[image: database table initialized]

Actual output:
[image: database table missing]

I've tried enabling Full Disk Access to my terminal on MacOS Security & Privacy.

Also ran the following chmod commands in the script's directory:

```
 ✘ kaiocunha@Kaios-MacBook-Pro  ~/Desktop/projects/git/go/api-go-rest  ↱ master ±  chmod 775 -R migration 
chmod: -R: No such file or directory
 ✘ kaiocunha@Kaios-MacBook-Pro  ~/Desktop/projects/git/go/api-go-rest  ↱ master  chmod 775 -R migration/docker-database-initial.sql 
chmod: -R: No such file or directory
 ✘ kaiocunha@Kaios-MacBook-Pro  ~/Desktop/projects/git/go/api-go-rest  ↱ master 
```

The whole code can be found [here](https://github.com/kaiohenricunha/api-go-rest).

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: You probably need to update your question with the contents of the docker-database-initial.sql file in order for anyone to help you

Comment: I have ran your docker-compose.yml and included the script at the table create and the container comes up fine and can see the wiki table created with 2 rows. So the good news is its not an issue with your config or script. However that leaves the question of

Comment: @NickW the script is included in the question

Comment: @NickW I've updated the question with more details and the repo link

Comment: @chris-doyle that's definitely good news, but still really weird

Comment: yeah I have tried also cloning your repo and running `docker compose up` and again can see the table loaded. I have left the db up if you want to look in the pgadmin at http://51.195.149.156:54321

Comment: Have you checked what your docker-compose up logs in place of the error I'm getting?